# Why Share on LinkedIn API return 400 Bad Request?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to post a LinkedIn share update via its [Share on LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) API using a PHP library [LinkedIn-Client API](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client). I've successfully authorized the user and I got the access token returned from it. I use the token along with this share API call. Here is my code:

```
$linkedInOAuth = new Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn(LINKEDIN_APP_ID, LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET);

if ($accessToken) { // assume that it is retrieved from session
    $linkedInOAuth->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    $postParams = array(
        "content" => array(
            'description' => "I'm so exciting to share a post using API."
        ),
        "visibility" => array(
            "code" => "connnections-only"
        )
    );

    $result = $linkedInOAuth->api(
        "v1/people/~/shares",
        array("format" => "json"),
        "POST",
        $postParams
    );
}
```

However I got 400 bad request error returned from this API call.

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleException: 400: Client error response [url] https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=xxxxxxx [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request thrown in ...\vendor\happyr\linkedin-api-client\src\Happyr\LinkedIn\Http\GuzzleRequest.php on line 26

What could be the problem?

#### [UPDATE on 2015-04-30 3:00 PM UTC]

[LinkedIn-Client API](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client) uses [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) internally for HTTP requests. I tried to use `GuzzleHttp` directly without using `Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn->api()`, but same error and no success.

```
if ($accessToken) {
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=' . $accessToken;

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->post($url, array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'x-li-format'  => 'json'
        ),
        'json' => array(
            'comment' => 'Check out developer.linkedin.com!',
            'content' => array(
                'description' => 'I\'m so exciting to share a post using API.'
            ),
            'visibility' => array(
                'code' => 'connections-only'
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException'
>   with message 'Client error response [url]
>   https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=xxxxx
>   [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request' in
>   \vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:89 Stack
>   trace: #0 \vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Subscriber\HttpError.php(33):
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Request),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Response)) #1
>   \vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Event\Emitter.php(109):
>   GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\HttpError->onComplete(Object(GuzzleHttp\Event\CompleteEvent),
>   'complete') #2 \vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\RequestFsm.php(91):
>   GuzzleHttp\Event\Emitter->emit('complete', Object(Guz in
>   \vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line
>   89

#### [UPDATE on 2015-05-05 9:40 AM UTC]

I copied and used both xml and json examples of [Share on LinkedIn API page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin). This time, the error changed to Internal Server Error.

```
if ($accessToken) {
    $format = 'xml';
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format='.$format.'&oauth2_access_token=' . $connect->accessToken;
    $postParams = array(
        "xml" => "
            <share>
                <comment>Check out developer.linkedin.com!</comment>
                <content>
                    <title>LinkedIn Developer Resources</title>
                    <description>Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement</description>
                    <submitted-url>https://developer.linkedin.com</submitted-url>
                    <submitted-image-url>https://example.com/logo.png</submitted-image-url>
                </content>
                <visibility>
                    <code>anyone</code>
                </visibility>
            </share>",
        "json" => array(
            "comment" => "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
            "content" => array(
                "title" => "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
                "description" => "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
                "submitted-url" => "https://developer.linkedin.com",
                "submitted-image-url" => "https://example.com/logo.png"
            ),
            "visibility" => array(
                "code" => "anyone"
            )
        )
    );

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    if ($format === 'xml') {
        $response = $client->post($url, array(
            'body' => $postParams['xml']
        ));
    } else {
        $response = $client->post($url, array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'x-li-format'  => 'json'
            ),
            'json' => $postParams['json']
        ));
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException'
>   with message 'Server error response [url]
>   https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=xxxx
>   [status code] 500 [reason phrase] Internal Server Error'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Github issue of Happyr\LinkedIn-API-client](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client/issues/25#issuecomment-99395103), some updates have been made in [0.5.0](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client/releases/tag/0.5.0) and it solved my problem. However, LinkedIn has unclear documentation about its Share API. The following information have to be noted:

1. The `comment` field is the sharing update content. The name `comment` leads confusing.
2. Using the field `comment`, URL is optional in the sharing update content.
3. The `content` field means snapshot about the content of the URL you are sharing. To describe more clearly, it reflects open graph meta tags;

   - `content.title` overrides `<meta property="og:title" content="..." />`
   - `content.description` overrides `<meta property="description" content="..." />`
   - `content.title` overrides `<meta property="og:title" content="..." />`
   - `content.submitted-url` overrides `<meta property="og:url" content="..." />`
   - `content.submitted-image-url` overrides `<meta property="og:image" content="..." />`
4. When the `content` field is used, the field `submitted-url` is required. The rest are optional. If it is missing, **400 Bad Request** would return.
5. The URLs included in the example codes of [LinkedIn Share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) would cause **500 Internal Server Error**. They should not be used for testing purpose.

The following is the correct usage of API using [Happyr\LinkedIn-API-client](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client).

#### (1) Happyr\LinkedIn - Using  the field `comment`

```
$linkedInOAuth = new Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn(LINKEDIN_APP_ID, LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET);
// retrieve $accessToken from db or session
$linkedInOAuth->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$postParams = array(
    'json' => array(
        "comment" => "PHPLucidFrame - The simple, lightweight and flexible web application development framework http://phplucidframe.sithukyaw.com",
        "visibility" => array(
            "code" => "anyone"
        )
    )
);

$result = $linkedInOAuth->post('v1/people/~/shares', $postParams);
```

#### (2) Happyr\LinkedIn - Using  the field `content`

```
$linkedInOAuth = new Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn(LINKEDIN_APP_ID, LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET);
// retrieve $accessToken from db or session
$linkedInOAuth->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$postParams = array(
    'json' => array(
        "content" => array(
            "title" => "PHPLucidFrame",
            "description" => "The simple, lightweight and flexible web application development framework",
            "submitted-url" => "http://phplucidframe.sithukyaw.com"
        ),
        "visibility" => array(
            "code" => "anyone"
        )
    )
);

$result = $linkedInOAuth->post('v1/people/~/shares', $postParams);
```

The following is the correct usage of API using [GuzzleHttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

#### (3) GuzzleHttp - Using  the field `comment`

```
// retrieve $accessToken from db or session
$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=' . $accessToken;
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post($url, array(
    "json" => array(
        "comment" => "PHPLucidFrame - The simple, lightweight and flexible web application development framework http://phplucidframe.sithukyaw.com",
        "visibility" => array(
            "code" => "anyone"
        )
    )
));
```

#### (4) GuzzleHttp - Using the field `content`

```
// retrieve $accessToken from db or session
$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=' . $accessToken;
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post($url, array(
    "json" => array(
        "content" => array(
            "title" => "PHPLucidFrame",
            "description" => "The simple, lightweight and flexible web application development framework",
            "submitted-url" => "http://phplucidframe.sithukyaw.com"
        ),
        "visibility" => array(
            "code" => "anyone"
        )
    )
));
```

The fields `comment` and `content` can also be used together.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess here but you might need to add json_encode to your $postParams before you send it to the API.

```
$result = $linkedInOAuth->api(
    "v1/people/~/shares",
    array("format" => "json"),
    "POST",
    json_encode($postParams),
);
```

ALTERNATIVELY

If that does not work I also notice the Linkedin Docs say the following. You could try adding these two headers (if you havent already).

> By default, all API calls expect input in XML format, however if it is more covienent for your application to submit data in JSON format, you can inform the APIs that they will be receiving a JSON-formatted payload by including the following two HTTP header values in the call:
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> x-li-format: json

Comment: Neither worked. I even tried `xml`, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you post the request which is being sent to Linkedin?

Comment: Please check my updated question. `json_encode` is not required because Guzzle has an json option which accepts array.

Comment: Can you try setting the content type to "application/json" - it looks like you have it as just "json"?

Comment: Yes, tried. Please check the error in the question.

Comment: Please check the edit **[UPDATE on 2015-05-05 9:40 AM UTC]**.

Comment: Well, I originally used the library you suggested. You can see this in my question. Please check the first code snippet. You might not understand the question well.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON post body needs to be corrected. Check:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

You need to follow either one of these formats.

1. Share via a comment containing a URL

   ```
   {
     "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG",
     "visibility": {
       "code": "anyone"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Share with specific values

   ```
   {
     "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
     "content": {
       "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
       "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
       "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
       "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
     },
     "visibility": {
       "code": "anyone"
     }  
   }
   ```

Comment: Please check the edit **[UPDATE on 2015-05-05 9:40 AM UTC]**.

Comment: LinkedIn API itself does not clearly describe it is comment or content share.